# Encryption using AES-128 in Java

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

I have a problem with ecrypting data using AES-128/ecb/PKCS5Padding+base64. I am using the following code to encrypt my data:

```
String input = "{\"action\":\"getQuestion\"}";
String key = "4288f0b8060ca1b682bf795f2617cfdc";
byte[] data = input.getBytes();
byte[] encrypted = null;
byte[] keyBytes = new BigInteger(key, 16).toByteArray();
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);
System.out.println(Base64.encodeBytes(encrypted));
```

I receive `6GuKXA6FFR+yMmO8ksAEOLL5e574a5tLob7tt5IG+jk=` after encryption but I can't decrypt on the server using a PHP function.

When I encrypt this data using the PHP function:

```
function encrypt($encrypt, $key=null) 
{
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
   $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $encrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
   return $encrypted;
}
```

I receive `6Wc3LPWvfJ7T86iG0igmdQaeZ8xs9qY419mAVWfNH+M=` and I can successfully do the decryption using the following PHP function:

```
function decrypt($decrypt, $key=null) 
{
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
   $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($decrypt), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
   return $decrypted;
}
```

With base64 encryption and decryption there are no problems; I only encounter the issue when encrypting using AES-128.

Comment: You probably are not using the same key on both sides.  Post all of the PHP code that populates `$key` including declarations of the constants in the current posted code.

Comment: A few things: 1) remove the IV, I don't know what it will do to the PHP function, but if it does anything, it will muck up the encryption/decryption 2) never use String.getBytes() without specifying the encoding to use 3) BigInteger.toByteArray() may return anything from 1 to 17 bytes, depending on the key value 4) ECB is definitely the wrong type of encryption for this. Fix those before trying anything else. I think you can safely use ASCII when communicating with PHP and using characters with code < 128.

Comment: @Paulo: that last "Use ECB mode" is probably a typo, I think you would want to suggest CBC mode here (or any other safe scheme that provides integrity protection/authentication).

Comment: @owlstead: Ah, thanks for the note. Horrible typo here.

Comment: This will not help for your current problem, but: **Do not use ECB mode**, ever, until you understand why it is insecure. Use CBC mode (with a random IV transmitted together with the message), combined with some authentication (e.g. HMAC).

Comment: I'm solved the problem. i'm use cbc on php and java. in php wrote function for unpack and pack paddaing5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with the IV or the padding as I initially thought. It is with how you are handling the key in the PHP code. If you are using the actual string `4288f0b8060ca1b682bf795f2617cfdc` as the key passed into `mcrypt_encrypt` and `mcrypt_decrypt` then you aren't using the same key as in the Java code. You will need to convert that hex string into bytes. You can do this in the following way:

```
$decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, pack("H*", $key), base64_decode($decrypt), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
```

Notice the addition of `pack("H*", $key)` to convert the value. I found that [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php#93328) in the comments for the PHP `bin2hex` function. This will fix the current problem. You may run into padding troubles when working with data of different lengths since PHP doesn't do PKCS5 padding. See [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php#69782) comment about implementing that missing function. Also, I'd recommend looking into CBC instead of ECB due to ECB's unsuitability and weaknesses for data encryption.

Comment: I tried on php without the initialization vector, but these get exactly the same, respectively, and can't decrypt the data generated on java.

Comment: Yeah ECB doesn't use an initialization vector. That is what makes it less secure than other modes. Once you get everything worked out, you might want to consider CBC with an IV instead.

Comment: @silentnuke: there is no guarantee that the default Java IV is the same as the default PHP IV.  You need to explicitly specify the IV at both sides.  At the very least, copy the encrypting IV over to the decrypting function.  Also, avoid ECB mode, it is insecure.  Use CBC or CTR mode instead.

Comment: I tried to encrypt the data using this service http://crypto.hurlant.com/demo/. aes128/ecb/PKCS5Padding.  The data obtained have successfully turned to decipher with the php function

Comment: Thanks for the tip about cbc, but first I would like to deal with this problem. In a flash Project no such problem, for encrypt we use library http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/

Comment: @silentnuke: Impossible, PHP mcrypt doesn't do PKCS5 padding.

Comment: @GregS: does not matter, the first block is not equal either, if I look at the Base 64

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the output from your Java method at the command line using openssl.  Java will default your IV to 0 if unspecified.

```
The file "enc.txt" contains "6GuKXA6FFR+yMmO8ksAEOLL5e574a5tLob7tt5IG+jk=" [corrected]
```

Run

```
openssl aes-128-ecb -in enc.txt -a -K 4288f0b8060ca1b682bf795f2617cfdc -iv 0 -d
```

The result is:

```
{"action":"getQuestion"}
```

Try your mcrypt_decrypt with an $iv value of 0.

Comment: if java functiob return 6Wc3LPWvfJ7T86iG0igmdQaeZ8xs9qY419mAVWfNH+M= the issue would not be, but returns  6GuKXA6FFR+yMmO8ksAEOLL5e574a5tLob7tt5IG+jk=

Comment: Whoops.  Typo when I wrote the note here-- not when I tested.  File "enc.txt" actually is the "6Gu..." string.